# Drawing attention to a question in another StackExchange site

Tags: support, exact-duplicates, cross-posting, stackexchange, se-sites

I asked a question in [CrossValidated Stack Exchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) site because it deals with probability distributions. But it is a theoretical question (although I think it does not involve high-level maths). I am not getting satisfying answers to the moment.

I want to keep my question there, but I would like to post a question in [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/) in order draw attention to my question, I mean, to ask users in Mathematics Stack Exchange to try to answer the question in CrossValidated Stack Exchange.

Would I be banned or punished for this practice?

Alternatively, I could duplicate my question here in this site, but I've read this is not recommended.

By the way, this is the question *in question*: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/147978/probability-distribution-for-a-proportion-based-on-continuous-quantities

Comment: This question seems related: [Can questions be “shared” within sites?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6190/can-questions-be-shared-within-sites)

Comment: You have probably already read them, but I will add some older discussions about [cross-posting](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cross-posting): [Moderator Supported (Official) Guidelines for “Legitimate” CrossPosting?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5085/moderator-supported-official-guidelines-for-legitimate-crossposting) and [Is cross-posted forbidden/discouraged on Stack Exchange sites? If so, why?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9337/is-cross-posted-forbidden-discouraged-on-stack-exchange-sites-if-so-why)