# Proper way of migrating a question from one forum to another

Tags: support, migration, cross-posting

I have a question about my Mathematics Stack Exchange post: [Including definite integrals inside definite integrals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2877146/including-definite-integrals-inside-definite-integrals)

I asked a question (link above) in the math forum. I am wondering if I might be able to find more interested viewers/potential responders if I post it in the Economics forum as well (since the question comes from an econ paper).

Is there a proper way to

(1) Ask the same question on multiple forums?
(2) Migrate a question from one forum to another but still have it available across forums.

My problem with (1) is that based on the OP's post [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20378/drawing-attention-to-a-question-in-another-stackexchange-site) it seems that duplication is "not recommended". But not selecting (1) and selecting (2) might mean I am reaching out to less viewers. I have read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069) and although it does show a way to resolve (2) partially, it seems that I will end up reaching less number of people this way.

I understand that I might be understanding the related posts/forum policies incorrectly. I greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: If you decide to crosspost (that is, post essentially the same question to more than one site), then it's incumbent on you to leave a link at each post to the other(s).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am going to try this. I see no way to upvote your comment though.